# Erro ao fazer INSERT - Laravel 5.1 + PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, laravel-5

Tenho campos de data no meu formulário, porém esses campos são opcionais. Quando eu preencho com uma data o cadastro é realizado com sucesso, mas se eu deixo o campo de data vazio recebo o seguinte erro:

```
SQLSTATE[22007]: Invalid datetime format: 7 ERROR: invalid input syntax for type date: "" (SQL: insert into...
```

O mesmo acontece quando deixo um campo do tipo inteiro em branco (número da residência por exemplo), parece que o postgre não aceita que seja deixado em branco, sei la...

A propósito, os campos foram criados como podendo serem nulos:

```
$table->date('nascimento')->nullable();
```

Estou utilizando laravel 5.1 com postgresql. Alguém me da uma luz?

Comment: Para campos int passe `0` como valor padrão, e `null` ou data atual para campos do tipo date.

Comment: blz, vou testar aqui @rray

Comment: Show de bola, funcionou! Obrigado @rray

Comment: O postgres é um pouco chato em algumas coisas mas tem funcionalidades bacanas também. Crie uma resposta para ajudar outros a resolver esse problema :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Resolvido:**

Na variável que recebe o valor do número(`integer`) eu fiz o seguinte:

```
($request->get('numero') == '') ? NULL : $request->get('numero')
```

Na variável que recebe o valor da data de nascimento(`date`) eu fiz o seguinte:

```
($request->get('nascimento') == '') ? NULL : $request->get('nascimento')
```